# awakeFromNib and loadView execute for different instances

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, instantiation, nib

I'm trying to understand why:

```
NSLog(@"self = %p", self);
```

in awakeFromNib prints a different value than the same NSLog in viewDidLoad?

This isn't a huge problem because I don't need the awakeFromNib but I would like to understand how it works.

The code that creates the controller is the following:

```
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    myViewController.image = tmpImage;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];
```

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when NSLog logs an object, it actually sends the `- description` message to the object. The address you are printing is actually the address of the returned NSString object containing the textual description of the instances. Since a new string is returned each time the message is sent, you get a different address.

If you want the address of the object you need to use:

```
NSLog(@"self = %p", &self);
```

Comment: I also get different values.

Also, the debugger gives me different values for the address of self (hovering over "self")

Comment: Not sure then what is causing your problem but you where using the wrong form of the NSLog statement.